# how can i read the student information from file because it can not appear

Tags: c++, string, file

i have written this program that  read the id ,name in function and course grade credit in another function and then  calculate total credits attempted, total credits earned, total grade points, and total credits.
after i finish written there is no errors but it show that things

```
#include<iostream>
#include <string> 
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>
#include<cstring>

using namespace std;

//functions prototype

int main() {
    //decleration
    ifstream inf;
    ofstream outf;
    int id;
    string name;
    string courseid, grade;
    int cridit;
    int tcattempted, tcearned, tcredits;
    double tgpoints;

    //opening file
    inf.open("students.txt");
    outf.open("report.txt");

    //check
    if (inf) {
        outf << "error, can not open file " << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    //header function
    header(outf);
    //read name and id function
    ReadIDAndName(inf, id, name);
    outf << id << "  " << name;

    outf << endl;

    //read course data function
    ReadCourseData(inf, courseid, grade, cridit);
    outf << "course" << "   " << "grade" << "   " << "credit" << endl;
    while (!inf.eof()) {
        outf << courseid << "   " << grade << "   " << cridit << endl;

    }

    // calculate function
    Calculate(grade, cridit, tcattempted, tcearned, tgpoints, tcredits);
    outf << "total credit attemted =" << tcattempted;
    outf << "total credit earned =" << tcearned;
    outf << "total grade point earned =" << tgpoints;
    outf << " grade point average =" << tcredits;

    //close file
    inf.close();
    outf.close();

    return 0;
}
//end of program


//function header

void header(ofstream& outf) {

    outf << setw(8) << "sultan gaboos university" << endl;
    outf << setw(8) << "student information sestem" << endl;
    outf << setw(8) << "contact show your id: show your name" << endl;
    outf << "****************************************************" << endl;



    return;
}

//function read name

void ReadIDAndName(ifstream& inf, int& id, string& name) {



    getline(inf, name, '/');
    inf >> id>>name;

    return;
}

//function read course data

bool ReadCourseData(ifstream& inf, string& courseid, string& grade, int& cridit) {
    bool exist = false;
    do {

        getline(inf, courseid, '/');
        inf >> courseid >> grade>>cridit;

    } while (exist);

    return true;
}

//function get grade point

double GetGradePoints(string grade) {
    double cradepoint;

    if (grade == "A")
        cradepoint = 4.0;

    else if (grade == "A-")
        cradepoint = 3.7;

    else if (grade == "B+")
        cradepoint = 3.3;

    else if (grade == "B")
        cradepoint = 3.0;

    else if (grade == "B-")
        cradepoint = 2.7;

    else if (grade == "C+")
        cradepoint = 2.3;

    else if (grade == "C")
        cradepoint = 2.0;

    else if (grade == "C-")
        cradepoint = 1.7;

    else if (grade == "D+")
        cradepoint = 1.3;

    else if (grade == "D")
        cradepoint = 1.0;

    else if (grade == "F")
        cradepoint = 0.0;

    else if (grade == "I")
        cradepoint = 0.0;

    else if (grade == "W")
        cradepoint = 0.0;

    else if (grade == "P")
        cradepoint = 0.0;
    else
        cout << "wrong " << endl;



    return cradepoint;
}

//function for calculations

void Calculate(string grade, int cridit, int& tcattempted, int& tcearned, double& tgpoints, int& tcredits) {


    ifstream inf;
    string courseid;
    double cradepoint;

    ReadCourseData(inf, courseid, grade, cridit);
    GetGradePoints(grade);

    int count = 0;

    do {
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            tcattempted = cridit + count;
        }
    } while (cridit != 'I' && cridit != 'W');


    do {
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            tcearned = cridit + count;
        }
    } while (cridit != 'I' && cridit != 'P' && cridit != 'F');



    do {
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            tgpoints = (cridit * cradepoint) + count;
        }
    } while (cridit != 'P');


    if (cridit != 'p' && cridit != 'I' && cridit != 'W') {

        tcredits = tcearned / tcattempted;
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: Suggest starting by eliminating all of the function not found warnings by moving all of the functions to above main. All sorts of things go wrong when the compiler can't find a function and tries to play fill-in-the-blanks. Next, test the state of `inf` after each read. Currently you have no way of knowing if any reads failed, and once a read fails `inf` will stay in the error state and all subsequent reads will fail until the error state is cleared and the offending data is removed from the stream.

Comment: i try it and i found that it can not read the id and the name from  ReadIDAndName function